# $\int_{C}((y^{2}-z^{2})dx + 2yzdy-x^{2}dz)$ is my result correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals

I want to verify if my result is correct. I need to evaluate this line integral:

$$\int_{C} \bigl( (y^{2}-z^{2}) dx + 2yzdy - x^{2}dz \bigr)$$

where $C$ is defined by: $C:\begin{cases}
 x=t \\ 
 y=t^{2} \\ 
 z=t^{3} 
\end{cases}$ between the points $O(0,0,0)$ and $A(1,1,1)$. I got

\begin{align*}
&=\int_{0}^{1}y^{2}dx-\int_{0}^{1}z^{2}dx+\int_{0}^{1}2yzdy-\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}dz \\
&=\int_{0}^{1}t^{4}dt-\int_{0}^{1}t^{6}dt+\int_{0}^{1}2t^{5}(2t)dt-\int_{0}^{1}t^{2}(3t^{2})dt
\end{align*}

and after calculations I got $\frac{1}{35}$ as result.

Is correct?

Comment: You are indeed correct. We get $$\int_{C}\left( \left( y^2 - z^2 \right) \, \mathrm{d}x + 2yz \, \mathrm{d}y - x^2 \, \mathrm{d}z \right) = \int_{0}^{1} \left( 3t^6 - 2t^4 \right) \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{35}. $$